# vue-resource y jpson

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Estoy tratando de consumir una API des esta URL, que devuelve un jsonp

http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json

Tengo este código

```
new Vue({
    el: '.App',
    mounted: function () {
        this.cojerDatos()
    },



    data: {
        losDatos: {}
    },
    methods: {

        cojerDatos() {
            const url = "http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json";
//let params = {callback: 'jsonCallback'}


            this.$http.jsonp(url, {params:{callback : 'jsonCallback'}})
            .then(response => console.log(response.data))


       },

    }
})
```

pero siempre me devuelve el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que el error está en que el callback que está devolviendo, se genera aleatoriamente, en vez de devolver jsonCallback.

Estoy utilizando la librería vue-resources, y por lo que he leído, cuando el método es jsonp, te genera un script con una callback llamada por defecto "callback", si no le pasas ningún parámetro, yo estoy intentando pasárselo, pero evidentemente lo estoy haciendo mal.

Os agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Le estas intentando pasar como parametro un nombre `jsonCallback` que es un string y deberia ser una funcion. De todas formas si quieres utilizar `then` no te hace falta enviarle ninguna callback

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si estas usando VUE, te recomendaria que uses la libreria Axios para hacer las llamadas REST.

Comment: He leído que axios no soporta jsonp, se necesita otra librería adicional, de ahí lo de utilizar vue-resource.

Comment: donde leiste eso? esa direccion devuelve un json comun y corriente. la diferencia esta en que el sitio acepta requests sin problemas de CORS.

Comment: y el json que devuelve esta mal formado.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/75, en este enlace lei

Comment: "I have decided not to support JSONP as part of axios. You can see the conversation here #15. Also take a look at this recipe as an alternative.".

Comment: de hecho en su documentación no viene nada referente a jsonp.

Comment: La url que te pongo, no devuelve un json si no un jsonp, de hecho con JavaScript nativo si obtengo las datos, creando unscript que llama a una función de callback. Si utilizas el método get de vue-resources, veras que no obtienes nada.

Comment: En el ticket que pasas de axios, esta la receta para incluir una llamada jsonp mucho mas simple. la probaste?

Comment: ocurre lo mismo, el fallo está en que los parámetros que ha que pasarle a la url tiene que ser http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json?callback=jsonCalback, pero está pasándole http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_recursos_turisticos/albergues_de_euskadi/opendata/alojamientos.json?callback=_jsonp7g49306h4o6, por lo que no ejecuta la función de callback